# Condition statements in sightly

Tags: aem, sightly, aem-6

In the Sightly templating language, for Adobe AEM6, how do I use a specific class  if a condition is true?

${properties.reduceImage} is my checkbox, so if the checkbox is checked then add the class if not then it doesn't  return anything. I'm not sure if I'm doing this the correct way.

```
<div data-sly-test="${properties.reduceImage}" data-sly-unwrap>
    <div class="reduce-image">
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The expression language of Sightly has a few operators that allow to do things like that.

In your case, you have two possibilities: the conditional operator, or the logical AND (`&&`) operator.

**Conditional operator**

This operator works like `data-sly-test`, but at the level of the expression. What is before the question mark (`?`) is the condition, and then come two parts, separated with a column (`:`). The first part is the output if the condition is true, and the second part is the output if the condition is false (which we leave empty in your example).

```
<div class="${properties.reduceImage ? 'reduce-image' : ''}">
</div>
```

**Logical AND operator**

This writing is a bit shorter, but also less explicit in it's intention. It uses the fact that like in JavaScript, ${value1 && value2} returns value1 if it is falsy (e.g. false, or an empty string), otherwise it returns value2:

```
<div class="${properties.reduceImage && 'reduce-image'}">
</div>
```

In both examples the class attribute will be removed altogether if the corresponding condition is false, because Sightly does remove all attributes with expression that end up being empty or false.

Here's the full documentation of Sightly's expression language:
http://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-1/develop/sightly/expression-language.html

Comment: Thank you Gabriel, You've really explained everything clearly. Thank you for the documentation as well. I'm going to study this all month.

Comment: When I implement this the css doesn't show. I names the css file. image-reduce.css and added a width decrease to a specific selector. When I check the checkbox nothing happens.

Comment: And when you output just your property, do you see it change based on your dialog? E.g: <p>${properties.reduceImage}</p>

Comment: To be honest, I don't understand what you try to explain. Maybe your property gets stored as a string, instead of a boolean. And the string "false" is evaluated to true by Sightly. If that's the case, you'd have to either adjust your dialog to store the value as a boolean, or to add some logic with Sightly's Use-API when reading the value. Else, there's not much I can help you, but make sure to very systematically debug the whole thing, and make sure the browser or the server doesn't cache any previous version of your CSS.

Comment: How to combine 2 if else statements in sightly, in javascript you can do this by (expr1 ? (expr2 ? xx : bb) : cc)

Comment: @GabrielWalt I need help to do this ${properties.title=='hompage'?'primary':' '} is it allowed?